# Show R commands interspersed with output

Tags: r

I can run an R script with source("foo.r") but just see the output. Is there an option to have the lines of the script being run interspersed with the output?

Comment: If you run it from shell: `R --no-save foo.R > out.txt` you should get both.

Answer (score 6):

Try playing with the `echo` and `verbose` parameters. You can get more details on how to modify the function's behavior by executing `?source`, which should give you the [documentation](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/source.html) for the function.

Answer (score 1):

The `knitr` package can create a report that includes the script interspersed with output and plots:

```
library(knitr)
stitch("my_script.R")
```

`stitch` produces a PDF using LaTeX by default.  You can get your output as HTML or as markdown/plain text with `stitch_html` and `stitch_rmd`.